# Why RecognizerResult doesn't contain the same JSON result from luis.ai

Tags: botframework

Why RecognizerResult doesn't contain the same json result from luis.ai

Here is the entities from RecognizerResult

[image]

and here is the result from luis.ai

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[This is an known issue right now](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1348) if you choose to use the `LuisRecognizer` package. Essentially it "eats" important details of the raw LUIS response.

My professional recommendation would be to eschew `LuisRecognizer` and just use the full on `LuisClient` directly. The only real reason to use `LuisRecognizer` is if you want that extra level of abstraction that allows you to work with other recognizer implementations. If you're "all in" on LUIS, then you probably want access to the full fidelity of LUIS anyway.

Comment: can you give an example of how to do this?